# Can I deal only with the GUI in java swing

Tags: java, swing

Can you please tell me that how can i create **only the GUI** in *Java Swing*
Also
Can I be the Master of Java dealing only with the GUI and not the Data Processing Code ...

I can deal with the code that involves the **GUI**(*for example- code to create a button*) but **NOT** the code that involves data processing(*for example- code to fetch the data from file*)

Please Elaborate on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help if you posted some example code to illustrate the difficulties you are having. Question isn't very clear as it stands.

Comment: @Piyush Gandhi : Well I really don't think so that, just by mere doing Front-End coding (Graphical User Interface), you can be THE MASTER of JAVA. But if you really thinking about on the lines of career prospective, then I will suggest you better start reading about [RICH INTERNET APPLICATIONS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application)  Regards

Comment: @Piyush Gandhi, I think you need to create the course **Master of Java**, with the requirement: **building GUI with Swing**, attend to it (you may get really bored in there) and that's it. After 6 months you will become the Master of Java.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should follow the model-view-controller design pattern. For example, you can use swing inside a `Display` class which has a reference to a `Model` class. `Display` will contain methods that update the GUI and can be called by code inside `Model` when data changes. It really depends on the exact scenario but that's the basic idea.

Read more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller

Comment: What? Do you really understand his question?

Comment: @loki2302 I'm assuming he wants to write the GUI part of an application and leave the data processing part to someone else. Something which MVC does well.

Comment: Great answer; however, isn't the Display class an Eclipse-only thingie (org.eclipse.swt)?

Comment: @loki2302 Yes loki2302 you are Right. I want to tell this only. Also more clear to this, I want to deal only with the Desktop GUI only and not the WEB based GUI...

Please assure me that whether i can or cannot...